# Parity pending transaction

Tags: transactions, parity, gas-price, pending-transactions, parity-wallet

I'm one of the many that tries to join the Status Network ICO using Parity. When I check "txqueue viewer" on top of the queue I see my transaction. As you can see below, it's there for a long time while other transactions in the queue have way less "First propagation" minutes and seem to go through. Even when they have the same GAS price / GAS values. Changing the GAS price doesn't work, as I don't have sufficient funds. 
Under "Signer" I have the option to edit the transaction, but there's a warning that it may not succeed. What is best to do now? Just wait till it goes through, or do you have other suggestions?
[image: parity transaction]